# gcc doesn't use my custom OpenSSL library with -L

Tags: c, gcc

I just built and installed the OpenSSL library without changing anything in it, only changing the path where it should be installed. But I can't get gcc to use it using -L.

I compiled my simplecon.c program with the following command:

`gcc -o simplecon simplecon.c -I/fullpath/customssl-3.2/include -L/fullpath/customssl-3.2/lib64  -lssl -lcrypto`

When I check with `ldd simplecon` it shows that it uses the default OpenSSL libraries, instead of my custom path ones:

```
libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x00007f2220fd3000)
libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f2220969000)
```

Even when I delete the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3` file, it still doesn't use my library under `/fullpath/customssl-3.2/lib64`.

When I check with `sudo ldconfig -v -N -X /fullpath/customssl-3.2/lib64` it finds the libraries in lib64.

I thought that gcc -I and -L my library would have priority for the linker over the default ones, but even when I delete the default ones it doesn't use it. So I am not sure what is wrong here.

**But if I change the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH it works as intended (it uses my custom library)** :shrug:. Is there a reason why the -L doesn't work in my case?

Comment: Well, yes. If it is a dynamic library, it is were it can be found (in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) at dynamic (run) time that counts. `-I` is only to tell the compiler were to find declarations (`.h`). Whose role is mainly to help the compiler to understand the code (it is because you include `math.h` that the compiler knows that it should raise a compile error if you use `sin` with 2 arguments. But once that checking done, once code is compiled, it doesn't matter any more).

Comment: As for `-L`, keep in mind that it is for both static and dynamic libraries (where to search for libraries at static linking time). And historically it was first for static libraries, of course. So, it was explicitely decided that, even with dynamic libraries, it would keep its role as "strictly for static linking" purpose. (One may wonder what is the point in specifying the at link time the location of a dynamic library, if not to specify where to load it at runtime. But that is not the point. When you say `-lssl`, it may be both a static or a dynamic library, depending on which is found)

Comment: If you are interested in a way to statically specify where to dynamically search for a library (so how to tell the generated executable where it is to find, when it will be executed, the libraries), you should look at `-rpath`